# CSS: Make float:right and float:left synchronizing?

Tags: css, css-float

First: please see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gamehelp16/77ssr/

So, these images:

[image]

[image]
<sub>(source: [placekitten.com](http://placekitten.com/200))</sub>

Uses the `float:right` property

and this image:

[image]
<sub>(source: [placekitten.com](http://placekitten.com/100?image=2))</sub>

uses the `float:left;` property

And if you see at the fiddle the third image (with the float:left ones) is not located beside the second image (the big ones)

My question is: how to make the third image is on the right side of the second image. I need pure CSS solution

Thanks

## Update:

i've figured out an alternative way to do it. it's by setting the second image's float to left :D

Comment: you float the image to the left and expect it rendered to the right? That makes no sense.

Comment: It works for me. If there is enough space, all images float to the top.

Comment: perhaps this is what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/77ssr/1/

Comment: @SvenBieder what i want is that the pic "floats" to left, but because there is big image so it floats to the right side of the big image

Comment: @JanDvorak: no, i want it to "fill" the empty space above it

Comment: Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/77ssr/7/

Comment: @JanDvorak no, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/gamehelp16/AzAjN/. but i don't want to use `margin` or `position`, because in my case it is longer, so ican put images on the right side of the image which i have problem with

Comment: You can't do this with just floats. The best you can get is http://jsfiddle.net/77ssr/10/

Comment: I think you need to find a different way to illustrate what you're looking for. Note that your fiddle is using the wrong kitten images...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The float element of css is relative to the page not the actual elements, i'll recomend you make 2 divs, and inside these divs the imgs to position, or you can simple use top or left elements. The choise is yours.

Comment: If you really understand what the asker wants, please tell me.

Comment: "The float element of css is relative to the page not the actual elements" Huh?

Comment: he want the third image to be at the right side of the other images, in his mind he thinks float: left counts the other objects.

Answer (score 2):

You could float the big one and have the little ones set to block display. [View on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uBByU/).

### html

```
<img src="http://placekitten.com/200" id="left">
<img src="http://placekitten.com/100">
<img src="http://placekitten.com/100">
```

### css

```
img:not(#left) {
  display: block;
}
#left {
  float: left;
}
```

To move them as a unit, you could set them in a parent container element [like this.](http://jsfiddle.net/nEHcZ/)

Comment: thanks, although i don't use your answer but it inspires me to get the solution

Comment: You don't need the :not bit since it's float:left'ed, but I included it just because, well, I don't want to apply the display:block to the #left and that is precisely what not is for!

Comment: @jmeas your answer's vote is not minus? plus i have upvoted your answer